# initial multiple screen with its own directory on a terminal

Tags: shell

I want open a screen on host1 and change directory to $HOME/bin.
host2 and change directory to $HOME/prj.

Here is my script, but the chdir can NOT work.

```
#!/bin/bash

start_host() {
    screen ssh $1
    sleep 1
    screen -X chdir $2
}

[ x"$TERM" = x"screen" ] || exec screen -ln -S xxx -c /dev/null $0
sleep 1
screen -X zombie cr
screen -X caption always "%{= wk}%-w%{= BW}%n:%t%{-}%+w%-="

screen /bin/bash
start_host host1 bin
start_host host2 prj
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that your problem is that you start screen (in function `start_host`) not in detached mode. That means the command `screen ssh $1` blocks the function and the execution process can't continue until `screen` finishes.

I would recommend to use `-d -m` to start screen in detached mode:

```
start_host() {
  screen -d -m ssh $1
  sleep 1
  screen -X chdir $2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution after try and error.

```
#!/bin/bash
start_host() { # <host> <dir>
  screen ssh $1
  screen -X eval "stuff 'cd $2'" "stuff \015"
  screen -X select 0
}

[ x"$TERM" = x"screen" ] || exec screen -l -c /dev/null $0 $*
screen -X caption always "%{= wk}%-w%{= BW}%n:%t%{-}%+w%-="

start_host host1 bin
start_host host2 prj
read -p "Press enter to quit all windows" a
screen -X quit
```